# Passing command line argument with spaces

Tags: c++, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have an application which reads specific commands from the command line and processes the command.
For Example:

I have a command called "setparamval" which is used to set the parameter value.
The syntax of this command while passing from the command line would look something like this:

```
setparamval <variable_name>,<value>
```

Supposing if I have a variable called "DESC" to which I would want to set the value as "ab cd ef gh"
I am passing the command line argument as:

```
setparamval DESC,"ab cd ef gh"
```

(i am passing the value inside "", otherwise the command line treats this as seperate arguments..)

Till here everything is fine...

Next, in my code, I am trying to extract the parameter name and the value from the command passed from command line using:

```
char inputCmd[TAGNAME_LEN];
strcpy(inputCmd,argv[1]);
```

When i see the value in "inputCmd", i am getting: "DESC,"ab cd ef gh".
Now i want to seperate the parameter from the parameter value (where the delimiter is ",") using:

```
char *savePtr = NULL;
char *src = inputCmd;  //argv[1];
ch = strtok_r(src, ",", &savePtr);
```

When i see the value inside savePtr, i get: ""ab cd ef gh".
There is an extra " getting added to the start of the string.
I am not sure why is this getting added.

Could you please help me in figuring out this problem?
Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: Can you eliminate the comma: `setparamval  DESC "ab cd ef gh"`?

Comment: As per the requirements, the command format requires the comma..

Comment: It appears cmd is stripping the 2nd quote but leaving the first. So just skip past it: `*ch = 0; ch += 1;`.