# How would you split strings from command line arguments? - Java

Tags: java, split, command-line-arguments

Basically in the command line, my arguments are going to be something like

```
-app app1 app2 app3 -env env1 env2 //the number can go higher then 3 and 2
```

where I have an enum for apps and an enum for envs

I know the easiest approach would be to use libraries and work with those but that is not an option for me. I tried to take what I read from [Java splitting command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372450/java-splitting-command-line-argument)

and from [Passing command line argument with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927779/passing-command-line-argument-with-spaces)
and put it together but it didn't work out

What I think I need to do is split when I see "-app" then add what is after that into a list until I see "-env" so I would want to split on the "-". I've never split command line arguments or arrays. This is what I'm trying so far.(I took the if part out because I know that part is working and doesn't involve anything with this)

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    boolean sawApp = false;
    boolean sawEnv = false;
    List<String> appList = new ArrayList();
    List<String> envList = new ArrayList();


    else if(args.length > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i ++)
        {
            if(args.equals("-app"))
            {
                sawApp = true;
                String[] apps = //this is where I am stuck
            }
            else if(args.equals("-env")
            {
                sawEnv = true;
                String[] env = //this is where I am stuck
            }
        }

    }
```

Then after it parses these it needs to take them and run into this method I have at the top of the code

```
public static Application chooseAppTest(String[] args) 
    {
        Application application = null;

        switch (application)
        {
        case ACCOUNTINVENTORY:
```

Comment: @Eran This is the first time I asked about splitting arrays.

Comment: "_would be to use libraries and work with those but that is not an option for me_" Why? If you want to reinvent the wheel you should give us a reason why.

Comment: @Takendarkk I'm running on java 6 so I can't really use a string join method. And using libraries would add complexity to the setup after I finish the program.

Comment: They look like the same question to me (or at least very similar). I also found [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001301/how-do-i-make-command-line-arguments-run-with-either-neither-or-both-arguments) by a different user. Was that you as well?

Comment: Why are you posting essentially the same question 3 times? This one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25018205/how-do-you-make-flags-for-command-line-arguments-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25016188/how-do-you-parse-arguments-for-a-java-program. The previous questions presented several possible solutions but he still posts again.

Comment: @Eran They're similar but I switched approaches and asked about the second approach this time. The other question wasn't me, this is my only profile and I just made it. This is an internship project and that looks like it's from the other intern team. We're doing the same project.

Comment: This problem already has a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25016638/636009

Comment: @DavidConrad that solution didn't work because it couldn't handle the spaces between everything and separating apps into one list properly and envs in another properly. Which is why I asked this question on splitting strings

Comment: That solution does put the apps and the envs into two separate lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get the array placed into a full String:

```
String args = "-app app1 app2 app3 -env ev1 env2";
String[] splitDashes = args.split("-");
List<String> appList = new ArrayList();
List<String> envList = new ArrayList();

for(String split : splitDashes){
    String[] splitSpaces = split.split(" ");
    if (splitSpaces[0].equals("app"))
    {
        for(String s : splitSpaces){
            if(!s.equals("app"))
                appList.add(s);
        }
    }
    else if(splitSpaces[0].equals("env"))
    {
        for(String s : splitSpaces){
            if(!s.equals("env"))
                envList.add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Okay, I finally came up with a solution for this, assuming that `-app` will always be first. This is for String[] args array:

```
public void DoSomething(){
    String[] args = {"-app", "app1", "app2", "app3", "app4", "app5", "-env", "env1", "env2", "env3", "env4"};
    List<String> appList = new ArrayList();
    List<String> envList = new ArrayList();

    int indexOfApp = -1;
    int indexOfEnv = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i<args.length; i++){
        if(args[i].equals("-app")){
            indexOfApp = i;
        }else if(args[i].equals("-env")){
            indexOfEnv = i;
        }
    }

    int countOfApp = -1;
    int countOfEnv = -1;

    if(indexOfApp != -1 && indexOfEnv != -1){
        countOfApp = indexOfEnv - 1;
        countOfEnv = args.length - (indexOfEnv + 1);
    }


    System.out.println(countOfApp);
    System.out.println(countOfEnv);

    for(int appIndex = indexOfApp; appIndex < countOfApp; appIndex++){
        appList.add(args[appIndex]);
    }

    for(int envIndex = indexOfEnv + 1; envIndex < args.length; envIndex++){
        envList.add(args[envIndex]);
    }


    Assert.assertEquals(5, appList.size());
    Assert.assertEquals(4, envList.size());

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! if I changed args to equal the entire array would this still work in the same way? There could be more or less arguments which is why I asked.

Comment: Well I figured app1 or env1 could be any name so equalling the whole array might not equal if they had different names.

Comment: The arguments that come into `main` in the `args` array are already separate strings, not one string delimited by spaces, so this is really not relevant to what the OP is trying to accomplish.

Comment: You are right @DavidConrad. Working on the solution now.

Comment: @AndrewGrinder the app1 env1 etc are enums so the strings would have to be converted into enums I think. So would this be enumName.valueOf(?)

Comment: @user3887792 When you run a java class the arguments are already split into individual strings on spaces. That's why `main` takes an array of strings. Your response just makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidConrad Everything was being put into one list and that was the only thing I could come up with so I tried to switch approaches...I'm sorry I'm a kid that is new to programming

Answer (score 5):

I would use [args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/).  Any attempt to "properly" parse command line arguments manually is an exercise in futility and wheel-reinvention.